# When edit data should id of data be stored in session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have list of posts that any user can edit.
When I enter edit mode of the post in a hidden field I store `PostId`.
Now I see that this is actually bad because user can change that hidden field and update some other post.
Is the `session` the only alternative to keep `id` of post that user edit, or there is some better tactic? 
Because my is really bad :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a better tactic:

Before updating the record check if the record that the user is trying to update belongs to the currently authenticated user.

You could write a custom authorize attribute that does this task for you. Here's [`an example`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10328876/29407).

Answer (score 0):

Try to just put the post ID as a hidden, not more fields.
Then, in the controller get the original post from databse using that id.

Then you have to check:

- If the id indeed pulls something from database (in case the post is already deleted or the user changed the id in your hidden).
- If the post to be edited is from that user/tenant (if it is from that user, and he changed the id in your hidden pointing to other post of his own, it is his responsibility).
- Add any other checks that you need in your logic (check if the user has permission to do that, or check dates, etc.)
- You can just update the fields that you allow edit in the post object from database, and save it (assuming you are receiving a `PostViewModel` in your action and not the `Post` Model itself.

This approach can be used in DELETE cases also, checking if it is OK to delete that item given an id.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it in a asp Hidden field and set the Visible property to false. This will let you access the value making control invisible on the page even in its rendered html tags

Comment: Webforms components should not be used in MVC.

Comment: @ZippyV : Thanks for outlining the forgotten part. +1 for the same