# Ensuring that only a particular user has access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

If I want to protect an action for being accessed by everyone except one user, how do I do that?

So let's say a user has a product. When they go to the EditProduct action, how can I prevent anyone else from accessing it? In the past I always used `User.Idenity.Name` and compare dthat to their username. But if someone logs in as `username` instead of `UserName` then the case breaks even though it's the same user.

Using `.ToUpper()` or something like this on every check seems very flimsy and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an Authorize attribute above the action like this:

```
[Authorize(Users = "username")]
```

I'm not completely sure if it is case sensitive, but this is the best method for protecting actions and controllers.  In addition, you can do the same with Roles:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

Comment: If no roles have yet been set are all users considered `Users` or is there no default? In other words can you use `[Authorize(Users = "username")]1 without any prior set-up?

Comment: Johannes wasn't clear if the goal was to protect the method using Authorize or to simply audit that the user in question has permissions (is the Creator or is some how otherwise granted permission). The default authorize action filter can only protect the action against exection (by name or role). If the goal was to allow only the user who created a product to edit the product this wouldn't work. A custom Authorize filter could be written if needed or you could do your own checking after fetching data from the database.

Comment: @Johannes [Authorize] will audit that you're logged in meaning of any role or any user. Only apply the Users or Roles if you have specific rights you want to grant

Comment: Oh right, so any user who is logged in can go to that action. Yeah that's not what I was looking for. I need it to only allow the user who is logged-in AND owns that product to edit it.

Comment: [Authorize] will get you part of the way, it will ensure the user is logged in. Since these action filters are created at build time they won't do what you want. Here is a good example of a custom written Authorize attribute: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes If you won't reuse the attribute much it might make more sense to just do the audit when the action is being exectuted.

Comment: Here is a SO question almost directly related to what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989100/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-authorisation

Answer (score 1):

String has a property for Equals:

```
User.Identity.Name.Equals("OtherName",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```