# ASP.NET MVC Controller Action Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

Just starting out with ASP.NET MVC. I'm working on a customer portal for our (FogBugz) helpdesk system. I understand that decorating my ActionResults with [Authorize] will require that the user is logged in, but what I'm not sure on is how best to ensure that a user can only access their own calls.

Once a user is authorised I can get their username from the User object, so should I be passing that from my controllers into the business layer and authorizing there, or is there a better way to do this (like a custom AuthorizeAttribute)?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should read this article below. it maybe help you to find the right way.

[Rick Anderson @ MSDN Blog.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx)
or
[How do i create a custom AuthorizeAttribute that is specific to the the area, controller or action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889541/how-do-i-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-that-is-specific-to-the-area-contro/4890406#4890406)

Comment: Thanks for that, I've read through those articles and that advice is useful to know.  However I'm not sure they relate to the specific query I had. I was more interested in where to perform the authorisation, in the AuthoriseAttribute or in the business layer.  In any case, I've decided to pass the user details into the business layer and validate permissions there as that seems the cleanest method.