# MVC 5: Custom AuthorizeAttribute and Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm trying to find a solution for implementing custom `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` by deriving from it and overriding some of its methods.
Every approach I'm trying, I'm facing with certain issues in the default authorization mechanism of the MVC 5 that prevents me from proper extending that.
I've done the huge research on this field on SO and many dedicated resources, but I couldn't get a solid solution for the scenario like my current one.

*First limitation*:
**My authorization logic needs additional data like controller and method names and attributes applied to them** rather than limited portion of the data `HttpContextBase` is able to provide.
Example:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    ...
    var actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
    var currentAction = actionDescriptor.ActionName;
    var currentController = actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

    var hasHttpPostAttribute = actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpPostAttribute), true).Any();
    var hasHttpGetAttribute = actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpGetAttribute), true).Any();

    var isAuthorized = securitySettingsProvider.IsAuthorized(
        currenPrincipal, currentAction, currentController, hasHttpPostAttribute, hasHttpGetAttribute);
    ...
}
```

This is why I can't implement my authorization logic inside the `AuthorizeCore()` method override since it gets only `HttpContextBase` as the parameter and what I need to make an authorization decision is `AuthorizationContext`.
This leads me to put my authorization logic to the `OnAuthorization()` method override as in the example above.

But here we come to the *second limitation*:
**The `AuthorizeCore()` method is called by the caching system to make an authorization decision** whether the current request should be served with the cached `ActionResult` or corresponding controller method should be used to create a new `ActionResult`.
So we can't just forget about the `AuthorizeCore()` and use the `OnAuthorization()` only.

And here we're returning to the initial point:
**How to make authorization decision for the cache system based on the `HttpContextBase` only if we need more data from the `AuthorizationContext`**?
with many subsequent questions like:

- How are we supposed to properly implement the `AuthorizeCore()` in
  this case?
- Should I implement my own caching to let it supply
  sufficient data to the authorization system? And how it can be done
  if yes?
- Or I should say good-bye to the caching for all controller
  methods protected with my custom `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`?
  *It must be said here that I'm going to use my custom `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` as a global filter and this is
  the complete good-bye to the caching if the answer to this
  question is yes.*

So the main question here:
**What is the possible approaches around to deal with such custom authorization and proper caching?**

**UPDATE 1 (Additional information to address some possible answers around)**:

1. There is no gurantee in the MVC that every single instance of the
   `AuthorizeAttribute` would serve single request. It can be reused
   for many requests (see
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4890406/3345644) for more info):

   > Action filter attributes must be immutable, since they may be cached
   >   by parts of the pipeline and reused. Depending on where this attribute
   >   is declared in your application, this opens a timing attack, which a
   >   malicious site visitor could then exploit to grant himself access to
   >   any action he wishes.

   In the other words, `AuthorizeAttribute` **MUST be immutable** and
   **MUST NOT share state between any method calls**.
   Moreover in the
   `AuthorizeAttribute`-as-global-filter scenario, a single instance of
   the `AuthorizeAttribute` is used to serve all request.
   If you think that you save `AuthorizationContext` in the `OnAuthorization()` for a request, you're then able to get it in subsequent `AuthorizeCore()` for the same request, you're wrong.
   As a result you would take authorization decision for the current request based on the `AuthorizationContext` from the other request.
2. If a `AuthorizeCore()` is triggered by the caching layer, `OnAuthorization()` has never called before for the current request (please refer the [sources](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) of the `AuthorizeAttribute` starting from `CacheValidateHandler()` down to `AuthorizeCore()`).
   In the other words, if request is going to be served using the cached `ActionResult`, only the `AuthorizeCore()` would be called and not the `OnAuthorization()`.
   So you're unable to save `AuthorizationContext` anyway in this case.

**Therefore, sharing the `AuthorizationContext` between the `OnAuthorization()` and `AuthorizeCore()` is not the option!**

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the OnAuthorization method is called before the AuthorizeCore method. So you can save the current context for later processing:

```
public class MyAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    # Warning - this code doesn't work - see comments

    private AuthorizationContext _currentContext;

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
         _currentContext = filterContext;
         base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
         // use _currentContext
    }    
}
```

**Edit**

Since this will not work as Alexander pointed out. The second option could be to completely override the OnAuthorization method:

```
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.AuthorizeAttribute_CannotUseWithinChildActionCache);
            }

            bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true)
                                     || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true);

            if (skipAuthorization)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
            {
                HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
                cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));

                var actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
                var currentAction = actionDescriptor.ActionName;
                var currentController = actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

                var hasHttpPostAttribute = actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpPostAttribute), true).Any();
                var hasHttpGetAttribute = actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpGetAttribute), true).Any();
                // fill the data parameter which is null by default
                cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, new { actionDescriptor : actionDescriptor, currentAction: currentAction, currentController: currentController, hasHttpPostAttribute : hasHttpPostAttribute, hasHttpGetAttribute: hasHttpGetAttribute  });
            }
            else
            {
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }

    private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }
        // the data will contain AuthorizationContext attributes
        bool isAuthorized = myAuthorizationLogic(httpContext, data);
        return (isAuthorized) ? HttpValidationStatus.Valid : httpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest;

    }
```

Comment: That isn't correct. First, there is no gurantee in the MVC that every single instance of the `AuthorizeAttribute` would serve single request. It can be reused for many requests (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4890406/3345644) for more info). In the other words, `AuthorizeAttribute` MUST be immutable and don't share state between method calls. Moreover in the `AuthorizeAttribute`-as-global-filter scenario, a single instance of the `AuthorizeAttribute` is used to serve all request.

Comment: Second, if a `AuthorizeCore()` is triggered by the caching layer, `OnAuthorization()` has never called before for the current request (please refer [sources](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) starting from `CacheValidateHandler()` down to `AuthorizeCore()`). In the other words, if request is going to be served using the cached `ActionResult`, only the `AuthorizeCore()` would be called and not the `OnAuthorization()`. So you're unable to save `AuthorizationContext` anyway in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Storing cache elements with required request data makes sense! I'll test this approach.

Comment: The edited answer doesn't work if AuthorizeCore is called by the caching layer.